# React native - unable to render component returned in function passed as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

**I have a function:**

```
handleSignUp= () => {
    if(this.state.password === this.state.confirmedPass) {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, 
        this.state.password).catch((error) => {
            let errorCode = error.code;
            let errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                return <Custom Component/>
            }
            else if (errorCode == 'auth/invalid-email') {
                alert('invalid email');
                return <Custom Component/>
            }
            else if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                return <Custom Component/>
            }
            else {
                // ... Some action is executed
            }
        });
    }
```

**In my render function, I have a:**

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Btn action={this.handleSignUp}/>
            // Btn is a component with prop 'action' which is a function passed to onPress in the Btn definition
        </View>
    )
}
```

But the custom components returned in `handleSignUp` do not render. Please help. I'm new to react, and there may be a simple solution, but I've googled extensively and couldn't find one.

**Btn Class**

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';


export default class Btn extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const btnStyle = this.props.btnStyle;
    return(
      <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this.props.action} background= 
      {TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('#60b0f4',false)}>
          <View style={btnStyle}>
            <Text style={this.props.textStyle}>{this.props.text}</Text>
          </View>
      </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you format that code?

Comment: Are you trying to only render when you press the button?

Comment: Yes. When <Btn />'s onPress is triggered.

Comment: Can you give the entire code?

Comment: @WilliamDarko i am not familiar with `react-native`, but if the same principles of react regarding state and when an element is rendered applies, this might be helpful: Only elements returned from the render method will be rendered, you return elements in your `handleSignup` function, which will be ignored. Instead if returning elements there use `setState(...)` in your promise/observable and render different elements based on this state in the render method.

Comment: Just FYI: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state

Comment: Thanks mate. I thought about that approach, but for some reason thought it was just code badly written.